# For a new domain controller

Tags: active-directory, domain, domain-controller

I have 2 series of IP.I want to make a domain controller in windows server 2003.all clients system are XP.I want to know can i make a domain server.if yes how its is possible ?

Comment: Do you already have an Active Directory domain, or do you need to create one?

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume you want to create a new domain; this is quite a simple operation, involving some basic steps:

- Install a Windows Server 2003 machine (with latest SP and updates).
- Give it a static IP address/subnet mask/default gateway.
- Configure it to use itself as its one and only DNS server (don't worry if DNS in not installed, this will be done automatically for you).
- Run dcpromo.exe
- Choose to create a new domain in a new forest.
- Give the new domain a FQDN and a NetBIOS name.
- Agree to install and configure DNS.
- Wait for the installation to complete and reboot the server.

After the domain is up and running, configure each and every client computer to use your new DC as its DNS server, and then join it to the domain.

Answer (score 0):

If by "I have 2 series of IP" you mean you have two subnets...

Then yes you can - the Domain controller doesn't care what IP address a computer has* it only cares that it can reach it (or rather the computer can reach the DC) - "2 series of IP" will not make a difference.

To make a Windows 2003 server a domain controller simply go Start->Run->[dcpromo](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732887%28WS.10%29.aspx) and follow the wizard.

**Ignoring sites/security/NAT/VPN or any one of the thousand things that could get in the way.*